# Error in Exporting Created Models to Database in EDM

Tags: c#, sql-server, edmx

I already had a Users table on the database with the following columns and data types

- Id - Int
- username - varchar(MAX)
- password - varchar(MAX)
- RefreshToken - varchar(MAX)

Then I added several columns to it as shown below.

```
public class User
{

    public User()
    {
        this.FollwedBies = new HashSet<FollwedBy>();
        this.UserFeedbacks = new HashSet<UserFeedback>();
        this.WishLIsts = new HashSet<WishLIst>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePictureUrl { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public byte IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedAt { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<FollwedBy> FollwedBies { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserFeedback> UserFeedbacks { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WishLIst> WishLIsts { get; set; }
}
```

. once I give the **Update-database** it returns the following exception

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

It also says that it failed to execute the following Dbcommand.

> DECLARE @var2 sysname;
>   SELECT @var2 = [d].[name]
>   FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
>   INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
>   WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Users]') AND [c].[name] = N'Username');
>   IF @var2 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Users] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var2 + '];');
>   ALTER TABLE [Users] ALTER COLUMN [Username] varbinary(max) NULL;

What would be the issue behind this error? Thank you very much in advance.